# JqGrid search in client side

Tags: search, jqgrid

There is a way to do search in client side after the server to response json data?
The jqGrid search example with only html/jscript and array of type local perform the search of the datas on client side, but when a have the same jqgrid deployed within the server, with json return the jqgrid hint/request for the server.
I would like to know about this behave on more deeply!

best regardless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements you need just add `loadonce: true` to the kist of jqGrid parameters. It will follows to changing `datatype` from `'json'` or `'xml'` to `'local'` after the first filling of the grid with the server data. So you can call [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention) to use toolbar searching of use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) to add button used in [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching). Any kind of searching will be implemented *locally*.

Comment: Oleg, I saw more options available very nice, but the loadonce parameter is the correct for this requirement. Tks man!